# Find an optimal solution formula from multiple variables analytically

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

If I have an optimization problem as follows:
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:for3b}
\begin{aligned}
(\mathbf{P}_1) \phantom{10} & \max_{\boldsymbol{\pi}} \phantom{5} \sum_{i=1}^I\pi_i(a_i - b_i).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{ s.t. } \quad \sum_{i=1}^I \pi_i a_i \leq S, \label{eqn:for3c}  \\
0 \leq \pi_i \leq 1, \forall i \in [1, I]
\end{eqnarray}
how to find the optimal solution formula of $\pi_i, \forall i \in [1,I]$? As far as I understand the optimal solution occurs if $\frac{\partial(\sum_{i=1}^I\pi_i(a_i - b_i))}{\partial\pi}= 0$. In this way I can obtain Lagrangian expression:
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:for3a}
\begin{aligned}
L(\pi,\lambda,\sigma) &= \sum_{i=1}^I\pi_i(a_i - b_i) - \lambda_1(S - \sum_{i=1}^I \pi_i a_i - \sigma_1) + \lambda_2(\pi_1 - \sigma_2) \\
&+ \lambda_3(1 - \pi_1 - \sigma_3) + ... + \lambda_{I+1}(\pi_I - \sigma_{I+1}) + \lambda_{I+2}(1 - \pi_I - \sigma_{I+2}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, since it has many $\pi$'s, how can I obtain the general optimal $\pi^*_i, \forall i \in [1,I]$ formula? Is there any suggestion using KKT conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is the linear programming (LP) relaxation of a *0-1 knapsack problem*, and an optimal solution is obtained by sorting in descending order the ratio $(a_i-b_i)/a_i$ and setting $\pi_i$ according to this order.  [This greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm) is optimal for the LP relaxation but only a heuristic if you require $\pi_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: It would be easy to solve using optimization solver. However, is there any way to find $\pi_i^*, \forall i \in [1,I]$ analytically, i.e., $\pi_i^* = ...$, for example using KKT conditions?

Comment: I didn't mean to use an optimization solver.  The optimal solution is to reindex so that $(a_i-b_i)/a_i \ge (a_{i+1}-b_{i+1})/a_{i+1}$ and then set $\pi_1 = \pi_2 = \dots = \pi_{j-1} = 1$ until $\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} a_i \le S < \sum_{i=1}^j a_i$, $\pi_j = (S - \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} a_i)/a_j$, and $\pi_{j+1} = \dots = \pi_I = 0$.

Comment: At the end, is it correct that $\pi_i^* = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(a_i - b_i) + (a_j - b_j)\frac{S - \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}a_i}{a_j}$? In this case, how to find the correct $j$?

Comment: No, after reindexing in descending order of $(a_i-b_i)/a_i$, the optimal solution looks like $\pi^*=(1,\dots,1,\pi^*_j,0,\dots,0)$, where $j$ is the smallest index such that $\sum_{i=1}^j a_i > S$.